# Determine which application the media keys will control

Tags: macos

When you press e.g. the pause key, the Mac OS will send that to whichever running application is playing media. How can I programmatically find out what application this is? And is there any other information available, such as the name of the currently playing media?

I'm looking for a command line tool, an API, or a scripting interface; I'm not picky.

Answer (score 3):

There was an app (no longer supported) called Media Key Forwarder that allowed users to decide which app would receive the Play/Pause command. [Its code is open source.](https://github.com/milgra/macmediakeyforwarder)

It wasn't the only one: [BeardedSpice](http://beardedspice.github.io) also allows users to control the play/pause button behavior, and it's [also open source](https://github.com/beardedspice/beardedspice).

I quickly browsed their source codes looking for a specific piece of code to embed here but it was not immediately obvious to me. Nonetheless, I think it's a good start and might help.

Comment: Currently, the best maintained app is probably https://github.com/Stillness-2/beardie